# Migration of data from a fuseki dataset to another fuseki dataset

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

Using Sparql queries I have to fetch data from a Fuseki dataset and need to load the results to another Fuseki dataset. Using the same query I should get the same results from the new dataset. Is there a way to achieve this?

### Query

```
SELECT  distinct ?id ?attribProductType ?attribName ?attribScaleValues ?attribUom ?attribDataGroup ?attribHighRange ?attribLowRange ?attribDefaultValue  WHERE  {   
?product rdf:type ?entity .         
?product :attribCompositeId ?id  .  
?product :attribIsLatest  "Y"^^xsd:string . 
?product :attribProductType ?attribProductType . 
?product :hasAttributes ?hasAttributes.
?hasAttributes :followsUOM ?followsUOM.
?followsUOM :attribName ?attribName.
?followsUOM :attribScaleValues ?attribScaleValues.
?followsUOM :attribUom ?attribUom.
?followsUOM :attribDataGroup ?attribDataGroup.
?followsUOM :attribHighRange ?attribHighRange.
?followsUOM :attribLowRange ?attribLowRange.
?followsUOM :attribDefaultValue ?attribDefaultValue.
FILTER( str(?attribProductType) = "precision_Test1") 
}
```

### Sample Output

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id                                                 | attribProductType             | attribName                       | attribScaleValues                 | attribUom             | attribDataGroup                     | attribHighRange       | attribLowRange    | attribDefaultValue                      |
=================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
| "8b25aa6f-7911-4c2d-8cc7-0796b94c3e44"^^xsd:string | "precision_Test1"^^xsd:string | "Voltage"^^xsd:string            | "N/A"^^xsd:string                 | "N/A"^^xsd:string     | ""^^xsd:string                      | "N/A"^^xsd:string     | "N/A"^^xsd:string | "No"^^xsd:string                        |
```

### Code

```
String host=FUSEKI_HOST+":"+FUSEKI_PORT+"/"+FUSEKI_DATASET+"/query";    
System.out.println("host:"+host);
String s2= readSparql();
System.out.println("Query:"+ s2);           
Query query = QueryFactory.create(s2);
System.out.println("query:"+query);
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(host,s2);
ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();        
OutputStream out1 = new FileOutputStream(new File("sampleRDF4.rdf"));
//added for rewindable resultset
ResultSetRewindable result =ResultSetFactory.makeRewindable( results );
System.out.println(ResultSetFormatter.asText(result));
result.reset(); 
System.out.println("Writing SPARQL result to RDF..");
ResultSetFormatter.outputAsRDF(out1, "RDF/XML", result);
qe.close();
```

The sampleRDF4.rdf is stored to new Jena and I am trying to fetch the results using the same query. But in the RDF the relations are in new fields like rs:varaiable and rs:value. Is there any other way to create RDF to maintain the relations in the Dataset as such?

Comment: There's probably several ways to do this. But as currently written your question is really too broad to answer. Can you show what you've got sofar (e.g. what your data and queries look like) and where precisely you are stuck?

Comment: I have updated the question with  query , sample output and code used for creating new RDF.

Comment: You might consider a CONSTRUCT query that returns a Model that you can then insert into another dataset.

Comment: Used CONSTRUCT query. Its working. Thank you AndyS